# (C++) Decision structure for third parameter in sort()

Tags: c++, sorting

I am working on a simple solution to a problem where I want to sort a vector of objects defined through:

```
class Person {
  public:
    string name_;
    double age_;
};
```

I am trying to modify the third parameter of sort() so that I can order my vector by age, but when two ages are the same it instead will order them alphabetically within that age.

```
vector<Person> people;
//code to populate vector
sort(people.begin(), people.end(), sort_decision);
```

I am unsure if it is possible to add a decision structure to the sort_decision code I have, roughly as follows:

```
inline bool sort_decision(Person const& lhs, Person const& rhs) {
    if (lhs.age_ == rhs.age_)
        return lhs.age_ < rhs.age_ && lhs.name_ < rhs.name_;
    else
        return lhs.age_> rhs.age_;
}
```

Thank-you for your help.

Comment: Think about what `return lhs.age_ < rhs.age_ && lhs.name_ < rhs.name_;` does when `lhs.age_ == rhs.age_`. Ask yourself what is the result of `lhs.age_ < rhs.age_` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

sort decision should be like this

```
inline bool sort_decision(Person const& lhs, Person const& rhs) {
    if (lhs.age_ == rhs.age_)
        lhs.name_ < rhs.name_;
    else
        return lhs.age_> rhs.age_;
}
```

because if `if (lhs.age_ == rhs.age_)` is true, `return lhs.age_ < rhs.age_` will always be false, and your comparator will return false if ages are same.